# Number encryption algorithm

Tags: encryption, numbers, logic

I have a list of numbers. I will be calling a service(let's say accountant service) which is going to perform some operation on these list of numbers and will return me the final result.

I don't want to pass my data in plain format. I want to encrypt numbers in such a way if service performs any arithmetic operation and return me the result, I will be able to decrypt it back with actual result.

Comment: Not a programming question so it's off topic, but look up "format preserving encryption" and "homomorphic encryption".

Comment: A lot depends on what the service accepts. What does the service accept?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Can homomorphic encryption be used on numbers as well

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' service accept a list of numbers and will return one output number after performing the calculation.

Comment: You may consider to look LightPHE library for Python. It wraps partially homomorphic encryption algorithms supporting multiplications or additions on encrypted data without holding private keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use something called [Homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption), which "is a form of encryption that allows computation on ciphertexts, generating an encrypted result which, when decrypted, matches the result of the operations as if they had been performed on the plaintext." With this type of encryption, they can be [Partially homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Partially_homomorphic_cryptosystems) or [Fully homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Fully_homomorphic_encryption). A fully homomorphic encryption can support [arbitrary computation (also called "bignum arithmetic" or "Arbitrary-precision arithmetic")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), whereas partially homomorphic algorithms cannot. As stated on the [cryptography stack exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) by user `mikeazo` in [this thread](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8822/what-are-some-disadvantages-of-homomorphic-encryption-schemes),

> ElGamal is a semantically secure, multiplicativey homomorphic cipher. Paillier is a semantically secure, additively homomorphic cipher.

The user also elaborates further and mentions a significant downside of this form of encryption:

> Homomorphic ciphers typically do not, in and of themselves, do not provide verifiable computing. In words, you encrypt your data, send it to the cloud and let the cloud compute on it for you. How do you know the cloud performed the correct computation? To get this sort of guarantee, other machinery is needed.

In your case, you would be sending it through an (I am assuming) reputable API, so this may not be a concern of yours.

From my research, your best bet will probably be [Gentry's cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Gentry's_cryptosystem). To use this (in a program), [HElib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib) should work fine.

In the future, crypto.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place for this type of question

Comment: do you think you could mark this as the answer to your question? I need that sweet sweet reputation :P